# Devices Layout [Android]

Tags: android

Using a eclipse + genymotion to testing my apps it's work well. The launcher icon inside the action bar work properly, and I'm using the action bar with the slide menu. Whenever I press the launcher icon it will prompt the slide menu from the left hand side.

But when I install this app into my own phone Lenovo A850(which is using only USB connected and detect by eclipse, but have no install the driver) it's icon is totally gone and I check the DDMS perspective view it's lost the frame layout compare to the genymotion emulator one

Sorry for my bad english , and is this possible my phone doesn't install the driver inside the pc so do it's happened? I'm using mac to connect my phone and it's default driver is only support window

Comment: what's the android verson in your smartphone ?

Comment: my android version is 4.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the menu.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_icon"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: still the same happen, I already disable the setting inside the default menu, the slide menu is custom one which is follow this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Comment: ya.its slidingdrawer. i think it may be the problem with actionbar.which actionbar are you using?

Comment: http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-nav-drawer-indicator.html#theme=light&color=33b5e5%2C40

Comment: Theme.AppCompat.Light I have used